# Can IIS supporting ASP.NET and WAMP supporting PHP coexist on the same server?

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, iis, wamp

Can IIS supporting ASP.NET and WAMP supporting PHP coexist on the same server?

We already have a WAMP stack setup on a Windows Server 2003 box to support some internal PHP applications, and I want to also setup CI Factory on that box which will try to configure IIS to support it's ASP.NET based dashboard.  I want to make sure that there isn't a big chance of fubarring the WAMP stack that is already there.  Will it be smart enough to handle *.PHP through Apache and *.aspx through IIS ?

Edit: Is there a way to get this to work on the same port?

Comment: Doesn't the L in LAMP stand for Linux.. I'm impressed if your running Linux on Windows :)  (I have seen DSL running inside Windows, but I wouldn't productionise that!)

Comment: @ck: I just assumed he meant WAMP.

Comment: Yeh sorry, notice I tagged it as WAMP, but somehow my wires got crossed while writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example IIS on non-standard port (e.g. 8080) and Apache redirecting traffic to IIS via [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Separate vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost lamp.example.com>
  # standard vhost configuration
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost aspx.example.com>
  ProxyPass / aspx.example.com:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

One vhost:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com>
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.aspx) www.example.com:8080/$1

  # ... standard vhost configuration for LAMP
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Both will run under IIS in a Windows server.

Comment: I ran outta votes today, I'll be back for the rest of you guys.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. I have IIS+ASP+MSSQL and XAMPP (apache+PHP+MySQL) installed on my development machine and both of them don't interrupt work of another another. Atleast while different ports are used

Comment: I ran outta votes today, I'll be back for the rest of you guys.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, yes. If it helps to provide "real world examples", the GoDaddy account that I'm currently hosting my sites on gives me both stacks. I have a couple SMF forums that are PHP/MySQL based and I have a web application that is .NET 3.5/SQL Server 2005 based and they run just fine.

Comment: Did you have to use different ports to get them to play nicely?

Comment: No. That may have been the way the hosting was setup, or because IIS7 was configured for it. But I literally removed all the PHP code of one of my apps and dropped the .NET app into the same folder and it ran just fine. However, instead of Apache, I believe the server is using FastCGI.